# Qual é o diagrama que melhor descreve um banco NoSQL?

Tags: nosql, uml, diagrama-de-classes

Quando se utiliza banco SQL, existem diferentes maneiras de mostrar o fluxo do sistema. No banco pode-se utilizar um ER para mostrar seus atributos. E para seu funcionamento usa-se um Diagrama de Classes UML.

Qual a melhor forma, de representar um banco NoSQL, para o usuário final, se tem algum diagrama que eu possa utilizar.

Comment: o NoSQL é um tanto livre, pode pensar nele como uma árvore na maior parte dos casos. Se bem que ultimamente tenho visto o pessoal usar NoSQL mais ou menos assim: https://c8.alamy.com/comp/JNFF2F/a-tangle-of-utility-wires-and-cables-above-the-streets-in-chandni-JNFF2F.jpg

Comment: @Bacco as modelagens NoSQL são os mainframes de antigamente https://i.stack.imgur.com/peDYG.png

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente não existe consenso e nem uma representação formal de um BD NoSQL.
Eu uso a UML (diagrama de classes) para representar as Coleções em um BD orientado a Documentos. 
Você conhece a ferramenta hackolade? Estou avaliando ainda, mas tem boas opções para diagramas de BD NoSQL.